# how to re-size the image on the fly

Tags: php, javascript, image, optimization, image-processing

i am planning to generate the RSS feeds in my site... For displaying images in RSS feeds, i am taking them from the source system(different from server). this is just to reduce the load and bandwidth usage in my server.

Need to resize the image on the runtime / fly as the image size is considerably large.

Please guide how this can be achieved

Comment: Do not do this. Fetch the images onto your server, resize them there, and store them as static resources. Resizing is extremely expensive

Comment: he can always resize it at upload time.

Answer (score 3):

> - *this is a function i'm using from a while, it is designed to automatically maintain the constrain proportion of the resized image*

**USAGE**

```
imageResize('old_image.jpg', 200, 'new_image.jpg');
```

---

```
function imageResize($image, $thumb_width, $new_filename)
{
  $max_width = $thumb_width;
  //Check if GD extension is loaded
  if (!extension_loaded('gd') && !extension_loaded('gd2')) {
    trigger_error("GD is not loaded", E_USER_WARNING);
    return false;
  }
  //Get Image size info
  list($width_orig, $height_orig, $image_type) = getimagesize($image);
  switch ($image_type) {
    case 1:
      $im = imagecreatefromgif($image);
      break;
    case 2:
      $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
      break;
    case 3:
      $im = imagecreatefrompng($image);
      break;
    default:
      trigger_error('Unsupported filetype!', E_USER_WARNING);
      break;
  }
  //calculate the aspect ratio
  $aspect_ratio = (float) $height_orig / $width_orig;
  //calulate the thumbnail width based on the height
  $thumb_height = round($thumb_width * $aspect_ratio);
  while ($thumb_height > $max_width) {
    $thumb_width -= 10;
    $thumb_height = round($thumb_width * $aspect_ratio);
  }
  $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_width, $thumb_height);
  //Check if this image is PNG or GIF, then set if Transparent
  if (($image_type == 1) OR ($image_type == 3)) {
    imagealphablending($new_image, false);
    imagesavealpha($new_image, true);
    $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($new_image, 255, 255, 255, 127);
    imagefilledrectangle($new_image, 0, 0, $thumb_width, $thumb_height, $transparent);
  }
  imagecopyresampled($new_image, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumb_width, $thumb_height, $width_orig, $height_orig);
  //Generate the file, and rename it to $new_filename
  switch ($image_type) {
    case 1:
      imagegif($new_image, $new_filename);
      break;
    case 2:
      imagejpeg($new_image, $new_filename);
      break;
    case 3:
      imagepng($new_image, $new_filename);
      break;
    default:
      trigger_error('Failed resize image!', E_USER_WARNING);
      break;
  }
  return $new_filename;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

the answer is simple:

**do not resize images on the fly**. NEVER do that.

unlike famous echo vs. print or single vs. double quotes problems, resizing images does **real** and **serious** harm to system performance. So, you'll end up with malfunctioning RSS feed and halted up server

Answer (score 1):

Please note that you shouldn't make a RSS feed with thumbnailed images on the fly. Instead save the, generated feed (with images), in a .rss file and serve that.

Now when you add a new item, you update your .rss file.

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

```
<Directory {DOCUMENT_ROOT}/tn/>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule \.png$ /tn/create.php [PT,NE,L]
</Directory>
```

Works great behind nginx.

Be very careful to ensure that you know PHP before coding "create.php". It would be easy to create a gaping security hole.

Note: This solution is only worth while if you have a very large amount of images that can't easily be statically generated.